# JavaScript won't work unless I use alert()!

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run into this issue from time to time and I don't know how to solve it. Here's my code that fails:

```
function on_lightbox_open() {

    system.contextBrowserInit();

    updateUrl(year + '/' + month + '/' + id);
    ads.reload();
    system.analytics.reload();

    FB.XFBML.parse($('#bottom_flap .fb_like').get(0)); // facebook
    $.ajax({ url: 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', dataType: 'script', cache: true });

    $('#lightbox .close').live('click', function(){
        $.modal.close();
    });
}
```

If I add an alert at the begining like so:

```
function on_lightbox_open() {

    alert('i work now');

    system.contextBrowserInit();

    updateUrl(year + '/' + month + '/' + id);
    ads.reload();
    system.analytics.reload();

    FB.XFBML.parse($('#bottom_flap .fb_like').get(0)); // facebook
    $.ajax({ url: 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', dataType: 'script', cache: true });

    $('#lightbox .close').live('click', function(){
        $.modal.close();
    });
}
```

It magically works. How to make it work without an annoying random alert?

Comment: Race condition. Your alert introduces a delay, which gives some other process time to execute first. Without the alert, that other process would execute later.

Comment: It looks like a race condition involving some other piece of your code.

Comment: @Jim Blackler Putting the code inside a set time out with a delay of 1000 milliseconds worked. What would be a good number to reduce that too that will still work on most hardware? Could I get away with like 50 milliseconds or maybye less?

Comment: @JakeRow123: Ideally, you would chain the callbacks correctly and not try to have an arbitrary and bug-prone delay like that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your use of .live() requires a fully loaded document and the alert just buys the browser some extra time. Try surrounding with $(document).ready();

Source: [jQuery-driven app. won't work without alert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470923/jquery-driven-app-wont-work-without-alert)

Comment: Good suggestion. Failing that, some information about the what you see when it doesn't work might help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<script>
    system.contextBrowserInit();
    //etc
</script>
```

Try this (HTML doctype):

```
<script defer>
    system.contextBrowserInit();
    //etc
</script>
```

Correct syntax for XHTML doctype is

```
<script defer="defer">
    system.contextBrowserInit();
    //etc
</script>
```

Comment: Defer is not cross-browser reliable as each one implements it on its own way. But might work